# Samba 4: group members not shown in "getent group"

Tags: samba4

I am running Samba 4 as an AD Server. Everything works fine, beside the members of a group is not listed by `getent group`:

```
# getent group
...snip...
LOCAL\Enterprise Read-Only Domain Controllers:*:3000040:
LOCAL\Domain Admins:*:512:
LOCAL\Domain Users:*:513:
LOCAL\Domain Guests:*:3000012:
LOCAL\Domain Computers:*:3000018:
LOCAL\Domain Controllers:*:3000034:
LOCAL\Schema Admins:*:3000007:
LOCAL\Enterprise Admins:*:3000006:
LOCAL\Group Policy Creator Owners:*:3000004:
LOCAL\Read-Only Domain Controllers:*:3000041:
LOCAL\DnsUpdateProxy:*:3000042:
```

but they are listed by the `id` tool:

```
$ id Administrator
uid=3000000(LOCAL\Administrator) gid=513(LOCAL\Domain Users) \
    groups=513(LOCAL\Domain Users),3000004(LOCAL\Group Policy Creator \
    Owners),3000006(LOCAL\Enterprise Admins),512(LOCAL\Domain \
    Admins),3000007(LOCAL\Schema Admins)
```

I need this to set group permissions in the `smb.conf`. I need this, because setting the rights with windows explorer on the share itself does not work. And I would also like to use these groups in the linux system itself.

Comment: have you tried with getent passwd Administrator?

Comment: That works as expected:
    LOCAL\Administrator:*:3000000:513::/home/LOCAL/Administrator:/bin/false

Comment: Have you succeed on setting up group permissions in `smb.conf`? I'm having the same issue... Everything works expect things related to groups :-/

Comment: I kind of did. I separated Samba4 DC from the file server and used the old samba3 code to serve files. What also worked was setting group permissions via Windows on the share. I think that is the expected way to go. Still there you have no groups in the linux system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the group, getent group just does not show the members.
samba-tool group listmembers 'LOCAL\Domain Users' should show the members.